# String variable shows as empty but length shows it to not be

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm using VB.net Visual Studio 2008 for a test fixture, writing and reading 4 USB virtual serial ports using the serialport class.

The odd thing that's happening is that, looking at the code below, ReceivedString shows, on mouseover, to be "" or empty yet ReceivedStringLength says 37.  How is this possible? Both variables are declared locally in a private sub.  Has anyone encountered this situation and could it be a bug in Visual Studio 2008?

```
    ReceivedString = SerialPortMaestro.ReadExisting
    ReceivedStringLength = Len(ReceivedString)
```

Comment: It probably has unprintable characters.  Look at `ReceivedString.ToCharArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

.NET uses `BStrings`, which are length-prefixed and null-terminated. So if the first character in `RecievedString` is the `null` character (`'\0'`), then it will not be printed, since strings end at their first null character.

Comment: Depends on how you 'print' them. `Console.WriteLine()` will show `'\0'` as a space.

Comment: Yes, but Visual Studio 2008 probably doesn't use `Console.WriteLine()` for its program debugging output.

Comment: Scott the poster here.  Debug.print shows a blank.  Debug.print

Comment: Oops, hit return before finished.  Debug.print ReceivedString  = 0 while Debug.print Asc(ReceivedString) = 0.  Don't know if this helps or not.

Comment: Are you sure that .Net uses BStrings?  I know that VB6 used them, but I think both C# and VB.Net are the same and I didn't think either use null terminated strings.  Can you provide some links that describe this?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The middle of the first paragraph from [one of Eric Lippert's blog pages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/19/strings-immutability-and-persistence.aspx).